# How to build custom lxml parser?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I need to build a parser for a message format a little bit different from regular XML.
Could someone who already experienced this, give some guidance? I did not find any similar question on stackoverflow. If there is one, I will be grateful for a link.

Message to parse looks like this:

I read lxml documentation (https://lxml.de/element_classes.html), but I do not understand the "honk" example.

```xml
[MSG]  
  NODE1=Node1content  
  [CHILD1]  
    CHILDNODE1=ChildNode1Content  
  [/CHILD1]  
  [CHILD2]  
    CHILDNODE2=ChildNode2Content  
    [CHILD3]  
      CHILDNODE3=ChildNode3Content  
    [/CHILD3]  
  [/CHILD2]  
[/MSG]
```

I expect the XML tree as output, on which I can get root and iterate through children.

Comment: Is this perhaps AMB format? It certainly looks like it. If it is, ask AMB to deliver its output as XML (`mbf_generate_xml()` instead of `mbf_generate()`). That will be *much* easier than writing your own parser.

Comment: @BoarGules: I do not know what format it is, I was only given this example; I do not know the functions you mentioned;

Comment: That was a guess. But if it was wrong guess then the advice obviously doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

The sample is small to know if this is an overoptimistic approach, but may be you don't need a custom parser to get a valid xml. `CHILDNODE2=` could be removed also with not much effort. Using python instead of bash shouldn't be that hard either.

```
cat test.txt | tr '[' '<' | tr ']' '>' | xmllint --xpath '//CHILD2' -
<CHILD2>  
    CHILDNODE2=ChildNode2Content  
    <CHILD3>  
      CHILDNODE3=ChildNode3Content  
    </CHILD3>  
  </CHILD2>
```